# xstream errors for serializing & deserializing

Tags: java, xstream

I am using xStream in Java to serialize a java object from a java library and deserializing it at the customer's side.

I have several problems:

If I do it like this:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();
xstream.setMode(XStream.ID_REFERENCES);
xstream.autodetectAnnotations(true);
Writer writer = new FileWriter(xmlFile);        
writer.write(xstream.toXML(myObject));
writer.close();
```

=> serializing is OK but deserializing: `Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException:  : only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not . (position: START_DOCUMENT seen .... @1:1)`

if I do it like this:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();
xstream.setMode(XStream.NO_REFERENCES);
xstream.autodetectAnnotations(true);
Writer writer = new FileWriter(xmlFile);        
writer.write(xstream.toXML(myObject));
writer.close();
```

=> I got serialization problem: `Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException:  : only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not . (position: START_DOCUMENT seen .... @1:1) 
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.XppReader.pullNextEvent(XppReader.java:78)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractPullReader.readRealEvent(AbstractPullReader.java:137)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractPullReader.readEvent(AbstractPullReader.java:130)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractPullReader.move(AbstractPullReader.java:109)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.AbstractPullReader.moveDown(AbstractPullReader.java:94)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.XppReader.<init>(XppReader.java:48)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.XppDriver.createReader(XppDriver.java:44)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:853)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:845)`

With xml:

```
<Test.Platform id="1">
    <TaskImpl id="1">
          <model reference="2"/>
          <name>process</name>
    </TaskImpl>
</Test.Platform id="1">
```

So Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please post the class you are serializing?

Comment: Hi, as I mentioned, I dont have the class structure, it is in a java library.

Comment: see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524775/error-reading-settings-xml  it appears there is a period(.) causing havoc

Comment: I have checked my xml output, there is no . in the document!

Comment: could you print out xmlFile to some other output and post that in the answer? And also post more of the stacktrace associated with the exception

Comment: No need to post stacktrace, I see your previous question on the same topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139702/deserializing-xml-file-from-xstream

Comment: This one I showed more errors of using XStream, I updated the question

Comment: XStream site is down and there was a few things I wanted to check with the API. In the meantime, you mentioned that you dont have the class structure; use a tool like JD-GUI to see the class structure

Comment: Yes, I can view the structure with JD-GUI. But what should I check the class structure? I mean which should be interesting to find out? Thanks in advance

Comment: @JoesyXHN check my answer, the problem isn't how you write the XML, it is how you read it back in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

so the thing that is overlooked here is how you are reading in the file. you are using

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();
xstream.fromXML("model.xml");
```

Which is where the period(.) is coming from in the error. The method fromXML is expecting the actual XML input and not the file name. So when it parses your xml (which is "model.xml" not the actual xml) it is giving the error. The site for XStream is down right now so I can't link to the API

Use a FileReader/BufferedReader in order to get the contents of the XML back. Something like this should work

```
XStream instream = new XStream();

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("model.xml"));
StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
String line;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
   buff.append(line);
}
Platform p = (Platform)instream.fromXML(buff.toString());
```

P.S. I was able to duplicate the problem, and fix it with the above

Comment: Hi Sean, Thanks. I just have tried your method of reading from BufferedReader but it is still the same error. :(

Comment: I found that, Xstream only works with: InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(dseirFile);