# Error in NonGUIDriver com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException

Tags: linux, unix, operating-system, jmeter

I have got this error when I am trying to execute the Jmeter script using putty on unix environment. Below is the error display on putty screen:

Error in NonGUIDriver com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException:  : only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not > (position: START_DOCUMENT seen >... @1:1)

Please let me know if you have ever faced this issue and you could be able to resolve this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [xstream errors for serializing & deserializing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175883/xstream-errors-for-serializing-deserializing)

Comment: Searching google for `Error in NonGUIDriver com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException:` shown plenty of results. Give it a try first

Answer (score 3):

I think you are making a mistake in the command line parameters, probably passing a text file to **-t** option.

Check this reference documentation:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options

Comment: This answer was correct for me. We had a .jmx file but accidentally removed the leading '<' sign, and then started getting this message. So to clarify this answer, you may get this error anytime the file you specified for -t is not a valid XML format file.